# Odoo - Show new field in POS receipt

Tags: javascript, json, odoo

I've added a new field in sale.order.line and pos.order.line called "resource_name"
I want to show it in the printed POS receipt, it came always empty.
**even in the DB it's correctly set in both tables**.
even when i try to console.log it it appears **Undefined**

sale.order.line:

```
from odoo import fields, models

class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):

_inherit = 'sale.order.line'

resource_name = fields.Char(string="Specialist Name")
```

pos.order.line:

```
from odoo import fields, models

class PosOrderLine(models.Model):

_inherit = 'pos.order.line'

resource_name = fields.Char(string="Specialist Name")

def _order_line_fields(self, line, session_id=None):
    result = super(PosOrderLine, self)._order_line_fields(line, session_id)
    vals = result[2]

    if vals.get('sale_order_line_id'):
        order_line_id = vals.get('sale_order_line_id')
        order_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].browse(order_line_id)
        if order_line:
            if order_line.resource_name:
                resource_name_exp = order_line.resource_name
                vals['resource_name'] = resource_name_exp
return result


def _export_for_ui(self, orderline):
    result = super(PosOrderLine, self)._export_for_ui(orderline)

    result.update({
        'resource_name': orderline.resource_name,
    })

    return result
```

JS:

```
odoo.define('pos_invoice_ksa.model', function (require) {
'use strict';

var pos_model = require("point_of_sale.models");
var SuperOrderLine = pos_model.Orderline.prototype;
pos_model.load_fields("pos.order.line", ["resource_name"]);

pos_model.Orderline = pos_model.Orderline.extend({

    initialize: function(attr, options) {
        SuperOrderLine.initialize.call(this,attr,options);
        this.resource_name = this.resource_name || "";
    },

    export_for_printing: function(){
        var json = SuperOrderLine.export_for_printing.call(this);
        json.resource_name = this.resource_name;
        return json;
    },

});
});
```

for the XML, I have already a working inheritance:
I simply added a new cloumn and used :

```
<tr t-foreach="orderlines" t-as="orderline" t-key="orderline.id">
<!-- working code -->
<td style='text-align:right'>
<t t-esc="orderline.resource_name"/>
</td>
<!-- working code -->
```

Comment: Have a look at this forum: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-add-new-field-to-pos-receipt-188881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the `resource_name` from `options` in the `initialize` function

***Example:***

```js
this.resource_name = this.resource_name || options.json.resource_name;
```